# await task inside another task

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, async-await

I'm working on a C# console application that will be responsible for running an array of tasks. The basic structure for that is as follows:

```
var tasks = workItems.Select(x => Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    DoSomeWork(x);
})).ToArray();

Task.WaitAll(tasks);
```

The problem is that DoSomeWork() is an async method which awaits the result of another task, which also needs to await a call to the Facebook API. 
http://facebooksdk.net/docs/reference/SDK/Facebook.FacebookClient.html#GetTaskAsync(string)

```
public async void DoSomeWork(WorkItem item)
{
    var results = await GetWorkData();
}

public async Task<List<WorkData>> GetWorkData()
{
    var fbClient = new FacebookClient();
    var task = fbClient.GetTaskAsync("something");
    var fbResults = await task;
};
```

I thought I would be able to support this notion of nested tasks with the call to Task.WaitAll() but the execution of the parent tasks finishes almost immediately. Putting a Console.ReadLine() at the end of the application to prevent it from early execution shows that the result will indeed come back later from Facebook.

Am I missing something obvious or is there a better way to block for my Task collection that will allow for this kind of scenario?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`DoSomeWork` needs to not return `void`.  The by not returning a `Task` the caller has no way of knowing when if finishes.

Additionally, it's already asynchronous, so there is no reason to use `StartNew` here.  Just call `DoSomeWork` directly, since it should be returning a `Task`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply that should have been an easy one. Feeling a little rusty over here haha